# Salesforce trigger - passing values from trigger record

Tags: triggers, salesforce

Objective here – to extract the account__r.id from the record in the trigger and add the value to a list with each for-loop…

CODE SAMPLE ONE

```
if (trigger.isinsert) {
for (loan__c oloan : trigger.new){
system.debug(oloan);
    Loan__c loanintrigger = new loan__c();
    loanintrigger = [ SELECT loan__c.name,account__r.id from loan__c WHERE loan__c.id =      : oloan.id];
    Account a = new account ();
    a.id = loanintrigger.account__r.id;
    //   debug to test insertion of value directly from trigger object.....        
    system.debug(a.id);
```

CODE SAMPLE TWO

```
if (trigger.isinsert) {
for (loan__c oloan : trigger.new){
system.debug(oloan);
    Account a = new account ();
    a.id = oloan.account__r.id;
//   debug to test insertion of value directly from trigger object.....        
    system.debug(a.id);
```

So… trigger one runs and completes its assignment. Trigger two fails due to “missing argument.”  I.e. – system.debug(a.id) shows that the id in the account object is null.

## 1, of course, requires a query for every record in the trigger.  No style points.

This foreshadows another important and vexing question….

In the context of an after delete trigger, not even #1 works because you cannot query DB for data that has been deleted!

Can anybody suggest alternate approach?  What am I missing?

Comment: You would probably get the best response for this question on the Salesforce [StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  You're probably right!